# Random module not working. ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)

Tags: python, random, numbers, range

In Python 2.7.1, 
I import the random module. 
when I call randint() however, I get the error:

```
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)
```

This error is caused by an error in the random.py module itself.
I don't know how to fix it, not does reinstalling python help. I can't change versions.

can someone please give me code for a working module or tell me what to do?

Comment: Can you post the complete and exact code that produces this error?

Comment: Pro tip: Just because the `random` module is at the bottom of the stacktrace, it doesn't have to have caused the error (in fact, that's it's unlikely). As already said, post your code (including stacktrace).

Comment: Please don't claim module isn't working before reading the documentation.

Comment: Pro tip: Read your stacktrace, your error message, your code, and The Fantastic Manual before you start blaming acts of (God, Gates, Guido, ...); the problem is much more likely to be an act of Goofy.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You called randint like this:

```
 randint(1,0)
```

That tells randint to return a value starting as 1 and ending at 0. The range of numbers from 1 to zero is as you surely realize an empty range. Hence the error:

```
 empty range for randrange()
```

Comment: I know that's how you call it. I'm calling it and it throws an error because the random module is corrupt.

Comment: @user551717 then you should do a diff between your version of the model and the source I posted and see what's up

Answer (score 8):

Trust me, `random` works just fine. You are calling `randint` with `b` < `a`:

```
>>> random.randint(1, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 228, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 204, in randrange
    raise ValueError, "empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop
, width)
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)
```

`randint` returns a value **between** the first argument and the second argument.

Comment: Note that the OPs exception is raised whenever `b < a`

Comment: Right, but (1,1, 0) is (a,b+1, b-a+1), so in this case he called it with a=1 and b=0.

Comment: okay, thank you. I forgot to add a person to the list of which the length is a before I called it.

Comment: @user551717: So you are gonna select one item from the list randomly? There is already a function for that in the random module. Please read the documentation. http://docs.python.org/library/random.html Also note that if you add to the second parameter, randint will give you a random integer between 1 and 1. Ie, it will *always* return 1.

Answer (score 2):

`random.randint(1, 0)` returns an error because whenever you use `random.randint(a, b)` a must be less than b. Try changing `random.randint(1, 0)` to `random.randint(0, 1)` to get a valid result.

Click [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) for more information about `random.randint`

Answer (score 1):

If you called `randint()` by itself, it will most definitely result in an error. You need to provide `randint()` with a range to choose from. `randint(a, b)`, where a and b are integers, should work, and if it doesn't, your Python installation is broken.

It would also raise an exception if b is less than a. Think of it like you're supplying a range: it would make sense to put the lower bound first, right? So put the smaller bound first.

If you really want to compare your `random` module with the correct one, the source is at http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/random.py?view=markup