# randint() error 'empty range for randrange' in the python random module

Tags: python

when I use randint() sometimes this error will appear:

```
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)
```

why is this/how do i stop it from happening?

im not doing anything wrong as far as i can tell, this error dosnt apppear on any specific randit() call and only appears every now and then.

the error takes me to the actual random module:

```
raise ValueError, "empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width)
```

Here is my whole program (i call randint() often)

```
    from random import randint

units = 5
food = 20
days_without_food = 0
SP = 4
print '------------------------------------------------------'
print 'welcome! starting a new game'
print '------------------------------------------------------'
location = 'plains'

def search(): #do2 create leadership skill or search skill
    global units
    global food
    global SP
    if SP > 0:
        SP = SP - 1
        found = randint(1,3)
        if found == 1 or found == 2:
            if units == 0:
                units = randint(1,5)
                print '------------------------------------------------------'
                print 'you recruited %s units!' %units
                main()
            a = units / 2
            ammount = randint(1,a)
            units = units + ammount
            print '------------------------------------------------------'
            print 'you recruted %s units!' %ammount #recruit a random ammount of units not over half ammount of already owned.
            main()
        else:
            print '------------------------------------------------------'
            print 'you did not find anything'
            main()
    else:
        print '------------------------------------------------------'
        print 'your army is too tired to look for anything'
        main()



def battle(): #do1 create villages with a random amount of units between 100-300
    global SP
    global units
    global food
    if SP == 0:
        print '------------------------------------------------------'
        print 'your army is too tired to fight'
        main()
    else:
        SP = SP -1
    if units == 0:
        print '------------------------------------------------------'
        print 'it is madness to go looking for a fight without an army'
        main()
    a = units / 2
    b = units * 2
    e_units = randint(a,b)
    e_units = int(e_units) #random ammount of enemy units reletave to  ammount of player units
    if e_units == 0:
        e_units = randint(1,3)

    guess = randint(e_units-5,e_units+5)
    if guess < 0:
        guess = randint(1,e_units+10)
    print '------------------------------------------------------'
    print 'it looks like the enemy has %s units' %guess #unacurate guess of how many enemy units there are
    print 'a: attack'
    print 'b: leave'
    action = raw_input('a or b?')

    if action == 'a':
        units = units - e_units
        if units <0:
            units = 0
            print '------------------------------------------------------'
            print 'you lost the battle and all of your units'
            main()
        else:
            a = e_units * 2
            ammount = randint(1,a)
            food = food + ammount
            print '------------------------------------------------------'
            print 'you won the battle and found %s food!' %ammount + '   after the battle you have %s units' %units
            main() # battle

    else:
        chance = randint(1,10)
        if chance == 10:
            units = units - e_units
            if units <0:
                units = 0 #attempt to leve
            print '------------------------------------------------------'
            print 'it is to late, they spotted you!' + '   after the battle you have %s units' %units
            main()
        else:
            print '------------------------------------------------------'
            print 'you leave without the enemy spotting you'
            main()

def change_location():
    global food
    global units
    global SP
    global days_without_food
    if food < 0:
        days_without_food = days_without_food + 1
        if days_without_food > 0 and days_without_food < 3:
            chance = randint (1,5)
            if not chance == 5:
                print '------------------------------------------------------'
                print 'you have no food, but your men are stll loyal to you'
                food = 0
                main()
            elif chance == 5:
                deserters = randint(1,int(units/4))
                units = units - deserters
                print '------------------------------------------------------'
                print 'without any food, %d men deserted your army' % deserters
                food = 0
                main()
        else:
            chance = randint(1,2)
            if chance == 1:
                men_starved = randint(1,int(units/4))
                units = units - men_starved
                print '------------------------------------------------------'
                print 'without any food, %d units starved to death' % men_starved
                food = 0
                main()
            else:
                deserters = randint(1,int(units/4))
                units = units - deserters
                print '------------------------------------------------------'
                print 'without any food, %d men deserted your army' % deserters
                food = 0
                main()
    days_without_food = 0
    SP = 3
    food = food - int(units / 2)
    places = ['plains','beach','river','mountain','sea','desert','hills',
    'forest','volcano','jungle','storm','village'] #do3 add more places
    location = places[randint(0,len(places)-1)]
    main()


def main(): #do1 Create nomadic and settled versions
    global units
    global location
    global food
    global SP
    print '------------------------------------------------------'
    print 'you are at a %s' %location
    print 'a:look for a fight'
    print 'b:look for supplies'
    print 'c:Take stock'
    print 'd:Move on'
    action = raw_input('a,b,c, or d?')
    if action == 'a':
        battle()
    elif action == 'b':
        search()
    elif action == 'c':
        print '------------------------------------------------------'
        print 'food: %s.  ' %food + ' units: %s.  ' %units + ' Search points %s.  ' %SP
        main()
    elif action == 'd':
        change_location()
    else:
        main()

main()
```

Comment: Please show the code that produces this error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random module not working. ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513818/random-module-not-working-valueerror-empty-range-for-randrange-1-1-0)

Comment: Most likely cause is that sometimes you're calling `randint(1, 0)`.  If so, stop doing that ;-)

Comment: I have shown my full code. im not calling randint(a,b) where b is bigger than a. it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

randint(a, b) should be called with the arguments a and b in which b should be greater than a. Else the randrange() method called by randint() will raise a value error like this:

```
raise ValueError, "empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width)
```

Check this source for random module with [randint()(line:237) and randrange() (line:173)](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/random.py?view=markup) methods for better understanding.

Comment: B is greater than A on all of my randint() calls. like i said, this only appears sometimes and never on one specific ocassion.