# How do I combine a clean signal with a noise signal given the snr?

Tags: python, wave

I need to combine a clean audio signal and a noise audio signal when a specified snr is given. I found this code that works for a few files but it doesn't for others. If this code can't work then can someone please suggest some other alternatives or the steps I should take in order to do it.

```
import argparse
import array
import math
import numpy as np
import random
import wave

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--clean_file', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--noise_file', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--output_mixed_file', type=str, default='', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--output_clean_file', type=str, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--output_noise_file', type=str, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--snr', type=float, default='', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def cal_adjusted_rms(clean_rms, snr):
    a = float(snr) / 20
    noise_rms = clean_rms / (10**a) 
    return noise_rms

def cal_amp(wf):
    buffer = wf.readframes(wf.getnframes())
    # The dtype depends on the value of pulse-code modulation. The int16 is set for 16-bit PCM.
    amptitude = (np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype="<i2")).astype(np.float64)
    return amptitude

def cal_rms(amp):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(amp), axis=-1))

def save_waveform(output_path, params, amp):
    output_file = wave.Wave_write(output_path)
    output_file.setparams(params) #nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname
    output_file.writeframes(array.array('h', amp.astype(np.int16)).tobytes() )
    output_file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = get_args()

    clean_file = args.clean_file
    noise_file = args.noise_file

    clean_wav = wave.open(clean_file, "r")
    noise_wav = wave.open(noise_file, "r")

    clean_amp = cal_amp(clean_wav)
    noise_amp = cal_amp(noise_wav)

    clean_rms = cal_rms(clean_amp)
    print(noise_amp,"  ",clean_amp)
    print(len(noise_amp),len(clean_amp))
    print(len(noise_amp)-len(clean_amp))
    start = random.randint(0, (len(noise_amp)-len(clean_amp)))
    divided_noise_amp = noise_amp[start: start + len(clean_amp)]
    noise_rms = cal_rms(divided_noise_amp)

    snr = args.snr
    adjusted_noise_rms = cal_adjusted_rms(clean_rms, snr)
    
    adjusted_noise_amp = divided_noise_amp * (adjusted_noise_rms / noise_rms) 
    mixed_amp = (clean_amp + adjusted_noise_amp)

    #Avoid clipping noise
    max_int16 = np.iinfo(np.int16).max
    min_int16 = np.iinfo(np.int16).min
    if mixed_amp.max(axis=0) > max_int16 or mixed_amp.min(axis=0) < min_int16:
        if mixed_amp.max(axis=0) >= abs(mixed_amp.min(axis=0)): 
            reduction_rate = max_int16 / mixed_amp.max(axis=0)
        else :
            reduction_rate = min_int16 / mixed_amp.min(axis=0)
        mixed_amp = mixed_amp * (reduction_rate)
        clean_amp = clean_amp * (reduction_rate)

    save_waveform(args.output_mixed_file, clean_wav.getparams(), mixed_amp)
```

The error I'm getting is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mix.py", line 55, in <module>
    start = random.randint(0, (len(noise_amp)-len(clean_amp)))
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\random.py", line 248, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\random.py", line 226, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d, %d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0, -47627, -47627)
```

Do I have to preprocess the signals?

Comment: Do you understand what the error message means?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random module not working. ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513818/random-module-not-working-valueerror-empty-range-for-randrange-1-1-0)